# How to override/proxy disconnectedCallback in Custom Web Components

Tags: javascript, function, proxy, overriding, custom-element

I am trying to proxy the `disconnectedCallback` of any instance of a custom element. Here is a cut down version of trying to do that:

```js
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `<button id="button">Click ME</button>`;

customElements.define("custom-test", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
      console.log("Disconnected Callback")
    }
  },
);

let test = document.createElement('custom-test')
test = (function () {
  const fn = test.disconnectedCallback;
  test.disconnectedCallback = function () {
    console.log("proxy function")
    fn.apply(test)
  }
  return test;
})()

document.body.appendChild(test)

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(test);
// Only outputs "Disconnected Callback"
```

I would expect to see the following output in the console:

```
proxy function
Disconnected Callback
```

But I can only see the second line, ignoring the proxy function. What do I need to do to override the function?

I tried using the `new Proxy` method but I can't do that because the `Proxy` element this creates cannot be used in the `appendChild` method.

If I explicitly call `disconnectedCallback` on the element

```js
test.disconnectedCallback()
// Outputs the proxy function too
```

it does call the proxy like in the last line it does call the proxy.

Comment: Why do you want to proxy it? Your ``disconnectedCallback`` _is_ executed by default

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I am writing a framework and I am wanting to block `disconnectedCallback` working running in a certain instance of `appendChild` where I am moving the element from one section to another of a custom layout . I am not sure what you mean by "Your disconnectedCallback is executed by default" every node operation I can see is ignoring it.

Comment: Then what is going to happen when I do ``extends customElements.get("custom-test")``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman you're going to get the standard class constructor with no proxy. Which is fine in my use case - I am trying to augment the method on the specific instance rather than the entire class

Comment: "*I am trying to proxy the disconnectedCallback of any instance of a custom element.*" - don't. Just fire an event instead, and subscribe `test.onDisconnect = () => console.log("proxy");`.

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately that won't work in my use case because I want to block `disconnectedCallback` from running in certain cases, which isn't possible as you describe. I can look and see if I can use events in a different way to achieve this though

Comment: Oh I see, then probably rather do `<custom-test ignore-moves />` where placing the attribute tells the component not do interfere with what you need to be done. But in any case I think it's a good practice to have the component know what is (not) happening instead of trying to wrap/proxy/decorate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this more I don't think it is possible. The issue is the functions defined on the class such as `disconnectedCallback` are defined on the object's prototype and can't be overriden in the same way (and if there is a way you probably shouldn't anyway).

I am instead going to look at creating a [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) for the class which handles the behaviour of conditionally calling the disconnect/connect functionality of the web component.